# How to get a Python Dataframe from ElasticSearch helpers.scan result

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dataframe

Suppose I have a helper functions like:

```
result_helper = helpers.scan(es, scroll='2m', query={"query": {"match_all": {}}} ,index="test", size=1000, _source=('logtime','host_name', 'kv', 'value') )
```

How I can get this data into a python dataframe?

With this approach:

```
result_helper = list(helpers.scan(es, scroll='2m', query={"query": {"match_all": {}}} ,index="test", size=1000, _source=('logtime','host_name', 'kv', 'value') )) 
df = pd.DataFrame(result_helper)
```

I get a dataframe, but with a list in the `_source` column:

```
_id                         _index       _score     _source               _type     sort
0   AVz3qBfbLK0jC-lSNFjT    test         None       {u'host_name': u'hostxyz', u'kv': u'Memory_an...    logs    [0]
```

How can I create a dataframe from the helpers.scan result with a column for each key in the `_source` list?
E.g.:

```
    hostname memory  ...
 1  hostxyz  1024GB  ...
 2      .       .        
 3      .       .
 4      .       .
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few considerations and tests I have developed the following solution:

With

```
result_helper_list = list(helpers.scan(es, scroll='2m', query={"query": {"match_all": {}}} ,index="check_mk_wnp_csh", size=1000, _source=('logtime','host_name', 'kv', 'value') ))
```

and

```
df_result = json_normalize(result_helper_list)
```

I get the list as columns (as desired):

```
df_result.columns

>     Index([u'_id', u'_index', u'_score', u'_source.host_name', u'_source.kv',
            u'_source.logtime', u'_source.value', u'_type', u'sort'],
           dtype='object')
```